# Changing db_table on Django doesn't work after migrations, and adding a user (AbstractUser) foreign key breaks __str__()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-migrations

This is a 2 problem post, which i suspect are somehow connected.
My posts app on Django doesn't migrate properly (I think), and adding the 'author' (Users AbstractUser model) breaks my code with the error:

> **str** returned non-string (type tuple)

whenever I try to add a row.

I changed the name of the table using `db_table` (so it will change Postss to Posts on the admin page) and added an output to the `__str__` function, I tried a few variations of output for the **str** function but non of them worked. I even tried to comment it out. and still. no changes in the table name or the error. I tried changing my **str** functions a few times and got the same result. when deleting the **str** function, I still get that same result.

I have a few wild guesses about this situation:

- it might not work with an abstract users class for some reason, and do not know to to work around this and why this happens at all. (removeing the `author=...` row resolves this problem but doesn't change the table name, but I do need the user fk there).
- it might not be migrating properly due to my environment or python version `Python 3.9.1`(?).

- PS: every change I have made included stopping the server from running and running the lines: `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py makemigrations`.

posts/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import Users


class Posts(models.Model):
    
    content = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey('users.Users', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Posts'


    def __str__(self):
        return self.content + " " + self.author.email + " " + self.timestamp
```

I will add my users model too:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


# https://rahmanfadhil.com/django-login-with-email/
class Users(AbstractUser): 

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username'] # removes email from REQUIRED_FIELDS

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.email, self.username)
```

[image]

Comment: Your model users  `__str__` returns a `tuple` but it must be a `string`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying return a `tuple`, it must be a `string`.

> def **str**(self):
> return (self.email, self.username)

Use the new-style formatting in [**Python**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Try this instead:

```
class Users(AbstractUser):
    ...
    
    def __str__(self):
        template = '{0.email} {0.username}'
        return template.format(self)


class Posts(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        template = '{0.content} {0.author.email} {0.timestamp}'
        return template.format(self)
```

or

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{} {} {}'.format(self.content, self.author.email, self.timestamp)
```

**Second Question:**

If I understand your question correctly, then to change the label for the model, you need to use `verbose_name`:

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Post'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
```

---

With option [**db_table**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table) you change **the name of the database table to use for the model**.

And see explanation how it works, from Django: if you have an app `bookstore` (as created by `manage.py startapp bookstore`), a model defined as `class Book` will have a database table named `bookstore_book`.

Then `db_table` must be:

```
class Meta:
    # your desired table name can you find in your database
    db_table = 'appLabel_modelName'
```

To list the tables in the current database for **PostgreSQL**, you can run:

```
python manage.py dbshell

\dt
```

See also Django [**db_table**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table)

Comment: Yesss this worked! I didn't know that doing this still uses the str function of the user. but my table name didn't get the value of `db_table='Posts'`. Why?

Comment: @W.Doch, If I understand your second question correctly, then to change the label for the model, you need to use verbose_name. I updated my answer.

Comment: So i found out that what i was looking for is `verbose_name_plural = "Posts"` and not `db_table`... django is still weird to me. Thank you buddy.

Comment: @W.Doch, happy to help 

Comment: ahhh i see that you edited your post ;) !

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `__str__` method to this:

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.content + " " + str(self.author.email) + " " + str(self.timestamp)
```

Also, you only need to migrate when you've made changes to the **models** not **model methods**.

Comment: Hi SLDem. ok. good to know. anyway, this doesn't work. i pasted a screenshot of my error for making my question more clear..

Comment: you don't actually have a `username` field on your `User` model mate, maybe thats the issue in your `User` `__str__` method?

Comment: I do since it's a class extension of the default user class (using the AbstractUser class) 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project I just changed it to use email as main identifier and not the username.